# How can i use my own customized Sharethis image along with sharethis plugin in my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, social-networking, sharethis

How can i use my own customized Sharethis image along with sharethis plugin in my website?

Is anything i can manually do in:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/website/js/share-this.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher:'fbcd68c9-0a9c-4974-9ada-e106a30e9194'});</script>
```

I just want to change the basic green color Icon nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the properties of this class:-

```
<span class="st_sharethis_custom">ShareThis</span>
```

Change CSS like this:-

```
.st_sharethis_custom{
    background: url("http://path/to/image/file") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    padding:0px 16px 0 0;
}
```

Also you can edit the img PNG directly from the Share This JS file:-

Search for:-

```
style.backgroundImage
```

replace the image location to your custom location.

Answer (score 7):

This is already [documented on the ShareThis site](https://www.sharethis.com/support/customization/how-to-set-custom-buttons/). Use the 'st_sharethis_custom' class on your link.

```
<span class="st_sharethis_custom">ShareThis</span>
```

Then specify a new icon to use with CSS.

```
.st_sharethis_custom{
    background: url("http://path/to/image/file") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    padding:0px 16px 0 0;
}
```